# Firebase A/B tests with Analytics and Custom defined goals

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-ab-testing

I want to see User activity which I see in Firebase Analytics in terms of Firebase A/B test variants as a Goal.

[While creating an experiment I don't see any goal related to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU2RU.png)
Also how can I customize goals like if I want to calculate Churn users rate which will be the opposite of Retention rate.
I want to calculate on something like this (Churn Rate = (100 - Retention rate)
[See Retention Rate here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cErU1.png)

I cannot do it using Custom events tracking